# How can I add scrolling to an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, layout, scroll, itemscontrol

I'd like to show items in an `ItemsControl` in 3*4 pages
One cool feature is that I can change the `ItemsPanel` of an `ItemsControl`:

for example:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Column='3' Row ='4'/>
...
```

How can I enable scrolling though? If the panel is a `StackPanel`, scrolling/paging is enabled.
But not for `UniformGrid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear whether you want paging or scrolling, but I think you mean the latter. That being the case, simply place the `ItemsControl` in a `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ...>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could use Template instead and put the ScrollViewer inside the ItemsControl and use it for the presentedcontent - this way the content is contained in the scroller not the entire ItemsControl.

```
<ItemsControl>
   <ItemsControl.Template>
      <ControlTemplate>
         <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsPresenter />
          </ScrollViewer>
       </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```